# How can I use multiple order by in real time database flutter to order data by specific field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to short **"realtime database"** result according to "date" in **flutter**. But I cant use multiple ***orderByChild('child_name')***. It throw an error. My code is

```
final String path = 'jsondata';
final _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
_dbRef.child(path)
.orderByChild('trade_code').equalTo('GP')
.once()
.then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  snapshot.value.forEach((key, value) {
    print(value);
  });
});
```

The result is
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wXJQ.png)

Now I want to sort the data by Date.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use multiple oder at the same time in `Firebase Realtime Database`. Please check the following doc:

[Firebase Realtime Database Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

To achieve that type of complex query I prefer that you should migrate from the `Realtime Database` to `Firebase Cloud Firestore`. Check the following resource:

[Simple and Complex Dynamic Query in Could Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Your Firestore instance would be:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('products')
.where('trade_code', isEqualTo: 'GP')
.orderBy('date')
```

Comment: I tried to make the query using cloud Firebase. But it doesn't work. Can you please make a query with where and order by with same time?

Comment: I edited the answer code. See the last portion. Did you get any error?